# Confusion of halting problem

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Show that the following problem is solvable.Given two programs with their inputs and the knowledge that exactly one of them halts, determine which halts.

lets P be program that determine one of the program will be halted.

```
P(Program x,Program y){

    if(x will be halted)

          then return 1;

    else

           then return 2;
}
```

since we know that exactly one of them will be halted,if 1 then program x will be halted.Otherwiae program y will be halted.

then we construct a new program call D

```
D(X,Y){

     if(P(X,Y) == 2)

         D will halt;

      else

         while(1)//D will not halt;

  }
```

lets S be aritbrary program.

So if we have D(D,S)

if D will halt then D will not halt

if D will not halt then D will halt

It impiles a contradiction same as halting problem.

But the question stated that it is solvable.

Comment: What if $P(X,Y)$ never terminates? How does $P$ compute "$x$ will be halted" in the `if` statement?

Comment: assume that p must return a result.because P is program that determine one of the program will be halted.I try to construct a counterexample similar as halting problem.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer because wiki also construct the counterexample for halting problem like that...so It assume the program exist and it can determine the  program halt or not.

Comment: So you have shown: if $P$ correctly determines whether $x$ halts  then there is a contradiction. The conclusion is: $P$ does not correctly determine whether $x$ halts. And you are not any closer to the solution to your problem.

Comment: Let me give you a hint: run both $x$ and $y$ in parallel.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer yes,I use the same strategy of halting problem duel with this question, so can I conclude that this question is unsolved because I construct a contradiction as halting problem.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer, I guess if we run them parallel,we can wait until one is halted?But I am confused that why program p in halting problem can implie that there doesn't exist a program can duel with halting problem.But my program p in this question can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with an important side note: what are the inputs for $X$ and $Y$ that they will halt on? you need to specify a specific input for the machines in order for the question to be well-defined (for example, the question could be "given $X,Y$ where exactly one terminates on $\epsilon$, find who halted." Or maybe, "given ... where exactly one always halts on itself as an input...")

I see what confused you there. The problem is indeed solvable: in $P$ emulate both $X$ and $Y$ and answer whoever halted first.

The problem in your solution is that an input to $P$ must be $X,Y$ where **exactly** one of them halts, and the other doesn't.

So, a proper input to $D$ must be a proper input to $P$. Now notice you called $D(D,S)$. To make sure that $D$ will return a correct output, we must have proper inputs: only one of $D$ or $S$ halts! But... If $S$ halts then your $D$ *also* halts and **this is not a proper input to $P$**, and therefore also not a proper input to $D$. Thus you cannot rely on output from $D(D,S)$ as it may not be correct

Comment: thanks but why "If S halts then your D also halts",I don't get it

Comment: Because we assumed $D,S$ are proper input to $P$ (and would get a contradiction later) and thus $P(D,S)$ halts and returns 2 (as we assumed $S$ halts. If it doesn't, then $D$ halts and try to think of a similar argument). Since $P(D,S)=2$, then by definition of $D$ we get that $D$ halts!

Comment: Thanks, I maybe get it.We first assume D,S are proper input to P,but in the end we always find out that D S both halt or D S both not halt So they are not the proper input to P,so function P can not be established,can I conclude like that?

Comment: Yes. This is the idea for the reasoning why $D$ doesn't create a contradiction (except for that your "halting" statement plus this one **do** show that $P$ cannot be created unless we assume proper inputs)

Comment: Essentially, this means that $P$ is not solvable unless you assume proper inputs (one halts and the other doesnt). Therefore, in $D$ you must make sure to give $P$ proper inputs, but as we have seen - $D$ doesn't satisfy this rule

Comment: sorry,one more question,have the general method to determine the problem is variation of halting porblem or not?

Comment: It is, the statement in your question explains why such a general version of $P$ would not exist

Comment: Sorry. So the solution is two program,P and S with there input p1,s1.P(p1),S(S1), untill one of them halt?Therefore,we don't need construct a new program for P and S which may cause halting problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110419/discussion-between-moly-holy-and-nir-shahar).